# Obtaining watershed area having elevation value to specific range from watershed polygon and DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have watershed polygon having minimum elevation 400m and maximum elevation 6000m.

How can I classify the watershed based upon elevation range so that I can calculate the watershed area having elevation values 400m to 3000m, 3000m - 5000m and above 5000m?

Comment: Have a look at the Reclassify tool in the Spatial Analyst toolbox, this will do it.

Comment: I have watershed raster with attribute value and count only. how can i reclassify according to elevation ?? please can you explain.

Comment: You would reclassify your DEM for the watershed.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the contributing watershed areas between elevation breaks you will need to use the Spatial Analyst Tools-Hydrology-Watershed tool to create a contributing watershed area at the 400m, 3000m, and 5000m point that intersects the main flow channel.  Then use addition or subtraction of the various outputs to determine the contributing watershed areas between your zones.

If you only want to determine the elevation area totals (regardless of flow)  then reclassify the elevation raster.  Then, if necessary, reclassify your watershed where is watershed = 1 and not watershed = NoData.  Multiply the two reclassified results together.  Open the attribute table of the result to tally areas between zones.